# Spring and Tiles3: Could not resolve view with name in servlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tiles, tiles-3

I'm new to Tiles and Spring MVC. Here's a simple example but I have not figured it out what's wrong with it after 2 hours.

Here's is my /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="gm.*"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.html">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" >
            <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" 
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="indexController"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
        p:viewName="index" />
```

My /WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

My /WEB-INF/tiles.xml

```
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="home.index" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/templateUser.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/home/index.jsp"></put-attribute>
</definition>   
</tiles-definitions>
```

My controller

```
package gm.controller;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class Home {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(ModelMap modelMap){
    return "home.index";
}
}
```

I located index.jsp in /WEB-INF/jsp/home/index.jsp

When I access this URL `http://localhost:8080/myproject/home.html`, it keeps saying the error in the title.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: do you have configured `view resolver`?

Comment: and change `<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`

Comment: @FlyingZombie well I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-1VjQznNZA&index=22&list=PLnQBGpefeAlvPe_Z2Y_Z7tmuuK4WRNuos and I didn't see them did that

Comment: I think you must start from basics :)

Comment: @FlyingZombie I'm trying. But can you help me with this one?

Comment: @could you paste your jsp files? is accessing to your controller method?

Comment: i haven't worked on tiles yet but i can help with simple `SpringMVC`